# Дублируются записи в БД при написании комментария

Tags: ооп, php

http://wowmoon.ru/1/?option=main&id_descr=5
При добавлении комментария дублируется предыдущая запись в БД. Подскажите как решить проблему, за ранее извиняюсь за тонну кода, просто не знаю в каком месте может быть ошибка.

```
abstract class ACore {
    public $pdo;

    function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=cp1251;dbname=blog", "root", ""); 
        $this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }

    protected function getHeader() {
        include("templates/header.html");
    }

    protected function getLeftBar() {
        include("templates/left.html");
    }
    protected function getFooter() {
        include("templates/footer.html");
    }

    public function getBody() {
    if($_POST) {
        $this->obr();
        }
    if($_GET['id_descr']) $this->cods = $this->capcha();
    $this->getHeader();
    $this->getLeftBar();
    $this->getContent();
    $this->getFooter();
    }
}

class main extends ACore {
protected $id;
protected $error;
protected $echoERROR;
protected $error_comm;

protected function capcha() {
//Вопросы
$q[0] = "Ананас";
$q[1] = "Бананы";
$q[2] = "Арбуз";
$q[3] = "Яблоко";

//Изображния
$imgq[0] = "images/cap1cha.jpg";//ананас
$imgq[1] = "images/cap2cha.jpg";//бананы
$imgq[2] = "images/cap3cha.jpg";//арбуз
$imgq[3] = "images/cap4cha.jpg";//яблоко
for ($iall=0;$iall<4;$iall++)//Формирование массива cods("сортировка","не закодированный код","закодированный код","изображение","вопрос","элемент содержит индикатор, правильный ли ответ")
{
    for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)//формирование кода из 8 символов
    {   
        $simvol = chr(rand(97,122));//выбираем любой английский символ
        $code[$i] = $simvol;//сохраняем в массив
    }
    $sort = rand(1,100);//определяем позицию картинки в капче (сортировка)
    $code = implode("",$code);//склеиваем код из 8-ми символов
    $cods[$iall][0] = $sort;//записываем в массив порядок появление картинок (сортировочный номер)
    $cods[$iall][1] = $code;//записываем не закодированный код
    $code = md5($code);//шифруем код
    $cods[$iall][2] = $code;//записываем в массив шифрованный код
    $cods[$iall][3] = $imgq[$iall];//записываем в массив изображение
    $cods[$iall][4] = $q[$iall];//записываем в массив вопрос
    $cods[$iall][5] = "false";//фиксируются что все ответы не правильные, мы еще не выбрали правильный =)
    unset($code);//уничтожаем код
}
rsort($cods);//сортируем массив
$truepars = rand(0,3);//выбираем правильный ответ (из 4-х картинок)
$cods[$truepars][5] = "true";//меняем у одного элемента массива индикатор с false на true. Тем самым выбираем элемент массива содержащий правильный код и правильный вопрос
session_start();//открываем сессию
if($_SESSION['code'])unset($_SESSION['code']);//если код в сессии существует то уничтожаем его
$_SESSION['code'] = $cods[$truepars][2];//записываем шифрованный код в сессию
return $cods;
}

protected function getComm($error) {
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comm WHERE descript='$this->id' ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$sm_read_comm = file("templates/comm.html");
$sm_read_comm = implode("",$sm_read_comm);
if( $row!="" ) {
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        printf($sm_read_comm,$row['author'],$row['date_comm'],$row['text']);
    }
} else echo "<p>Комментариев нет, вы будете первым</p>";

$form = file("templates/comm_form.html");
$form = implode("",$form);

if($error != "")//если есть ошибки
{
    $error = explode("|",$error);
    $this->echoERROR .= "<p style='color:red;margin:0px;'>Обнаружены следующие ошибки:</p>";
    for($i=0;isset($error[$i]);$i++)
    {
        if($error[$i] != "")$this->echoERROR .= "<p style='color:red;margin:0px;'>>$error[$i]</p>";
    }
$form = sprintf($form,$this->echoERROR);
} else $form = sprintf($form,"");
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $form = str_replace("[_code".$i."]",$this->cods[$i][1],$form);//вставляем 4 кода в форму
    $form = str_replace("[_img".$i."]",$this->cods[$i][3],$form);//вставляем 4 изображения в форму
    if($this->cods[$i][5] == "true")$form = str_replace("[_q]",$this->cods[$i][4],$form);//вклеиваем вопрос в форму
}
//капча

if($chpu == 0)$link = "index.php?option=main&id_descr=".$this->id;//...динамическая
else//Если ЧПУ включено то
{
    //выводим имя ЧПУ из базы данных по id поста
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT nameurl FROM pop WHERE id='$descript'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $link = "descript/".$myrow_link['nameurl'];//склеиваем ЧПУ
}
$form = str_replace("[_action]",$link,$form);//ссылка обработчика
$form = str_replace("[_id]",$this->id,$form);

echo $form;

}


//--------------ОБРАБОТЧИК КОММЕТАРИЕВ
protected function obr() {
    if(isset($_POST['id_comm']))$id_comm = $_POST['id_comm'];
    if(isset($_POST['txt_comm']))$txt_comm = $_POST['txt_comm'];
    if(isset($_POST['author_comm']))$author_comm = $_POST['author_comm'];
    if(isset($_POST['code_comm']))$code_comm = $_POST['code_comm']; 

    $date_day = date("d");
    $date_month = date("m");
    $date_year = date("Y");
    $date_time = date("H:i");
    $date_comm = $date_day."/".$date_month."/".$date_year." ".$date_time;
    if($id_comm & $txt_comm & $author_comm & $code_comm) {
        $id_comm = htmlspecialchars($id_comm);
        $txt_comm = htmlspecialchars($txt_comm);

        if($code_comm != "")
        {
            session_start();
            if( md5($code_comm) != $_SESSION['code'] )$this->error_comm .= "Вы выбрали не ту картинку!|";
            unset($_SESSION['code']);
            session_destroy();
        }
        else $error_comm .= "Вы не подтвердили, что Вы человек|";

        if($author_comm != "" AND $author_comm != "Автор*")
        {
            if(!preg_match("/^[-_0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+$/s",$author_comm))$this->error_comm .= "Не правильный формат поля 'Автор'|";
            if(mb_strlen($author_comm) > 25)$this->error_comm .= "В поле 'Автор' слишком много символов|";
        }
        else $this->error_comm .= "Вы не заполнили поле 'Автор'|";

        if($txt_comm == "" || $txt_comm == "Введите текст*")$this->error_comm .="Вы не ввели текст!|"; 

        if(!isset($this->error_comm)) {
        $id_comm = str_replace("'","&#039",$id_comm);
        $txt_comm = str_replace("'","&#039",$txt_comm);

        $txt_comm = str_replace("\n","<BR>",$txt_comm);

            //Добавляем сообщение в базу данных
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comm (author,text,date_comm,descript) 
        VALUES ('$author_comm','$txt_comm','$date_comm','$id_comm')");
        $stmt->execute();

        if( !$stmt->execute() ) echo "Не удалось добавить комментарий в БД=(";

        header("location: ".getenv('HTTP_REFERER'));
        exit;
        }
    }

}

protected function getContent() {
    if($_GET['id_descr']) {
    $this->id = $_GET['id_descr'];
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pop WHERE id = '$this->id'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if( $row!="" ) {

    $sm_read = file("templates/text.html");
    $sm_read = implode("",$sm_read);

    echo "<div id='content'>";
    printf($sm_read,$row['img'],$row['url'],$row['title'],$row['price'],$row['article'],$row['text']);
    //--------вывод комментариев
    self::getComm($this->error_comm);
    echo "</div>";
        } else {echo "<div id='content'><h4 align='center'>Товара с данным id не существует.</div></h4>";};
    } else {
        $sm_read_main = file("templates/main.html");
        $sm_read_main = implode("",$sm_read_main);
        echo $sm_read_main;

        $sm_read_pop = file("templates/pop.html");
        $sm_read_pop = implode("",$sm_read_pop);


        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pop");
        if(!$stmt->execute()) echo "<div id='content'><h4 align='center'>Нет записей в БД.</div></h4>";
        while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
            printf($sm_read_pop,$row['id'],$row['img'],$row['id'],$row['title'],$row['price']);
        }
        echo '  </div>
              </div>
              </div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

да все просто :)

```
$stmt->execute();
if( !$stmt->execute() ) echo "Не удалось добавить комментарий в БД=(";
```

вот тут вы 2 раза пишете коммент :)

```
$returncode = $stmt->execute();
if( !$returncode ) echo "Не удалось добавить комментарий в БД=(";
```

Вот так будет правильнееее

Comment: Исправил. Теперь при добавлении коммента добавляется предыдущий введенный.((((((

Comment: Почистите куки, почситите базу... тяжко код както читается...

Comment: Да)))) спасибо за наведение на мысль)))   
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pop WHERE id = '$this->id'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();  тут ошибка, вот только как ее исправить?

Comment: Добавляется куда? ибо тут выборка...

Comment: тут  $row = $stmt->fetch() нужно как то подругому записать чтобы потом сделать проверку на наличие данных в БД

Comment: Почему? Добавляется куда, в базу? или в вывод?

Comment: Почитайте это из мануала:
'HTTP_REFERER' 
Адрес страницы (если есть), которая привела браузер пользователя на эту страницу. Этот заголовок устанавливается веб-браузером пользователя. Не все браузеры устанавливают его и некоторые в качестве дополнительной возможности позволяют изменять содержимое заголовка HTTP_REFERER. Одним словом, в самом деле ему нельзя доверять.

Вы уверены, что вам нужно именно перенаправление на страницу-реферера, может просто $_REQUEST['URI']?? Код слишком длинный, лень разбираться просто ))

Answer (score -1):

добавляется в базу. Из-за этой строки выводились все коменты кроме последнего.